# Swagger UI put my every endpoint in the "default" group. Why is it doing it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui

Swagger UI put my every endpoint in the "default" group

Here's the JSON it gets (don't ask how I got it). Notice there are no tags (I also tried empty lists instead of nulls which are not serialized by Jackson)

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.3",
  "info": {
    "title": "Api Documentation",
    "description": "Api Documentation",
    "termsOfService": "urn:tos",
    "contact": {    },
    "license": {
      "name": "Apache 2.0",
      "url": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"
    },
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "https://localhost:8080",
      "description": "Api-Gateway-V2"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/api/v1/hello-world": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "getHelloWorld",
        "operationId": "getHelloWorldUsingGET",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SuccessMessage",
                  "exampleSetFlag": false
                },
                "exampleSetFlag": false
              }
            }
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "Not Found"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/api/v1/joy": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "getMessageOfJoy",
        "operationId": "getMessageOfJoyUsingGET",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/SuccessMessage",
                  "exampleSetFlag": false
                },
                "exampleSetFlag": false
              }
            }
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "Not Found"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/api/v1/error": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "error",
        "operationId": "errorUsingGET",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage",
                  "exampleSetFlag": false
                },
                "exampleSetFlag": false
              }
            }
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "Not Found"
          }
        }
      },
      "put": {
        "summary": "error",
        "operationId": "errorUsingPUT",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage",
                  "exampleSetFlag": false
                },
                "exampleSetFlag": false
              }
            }
          },
          "201": {
            "description": "Created"
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "Not Found"
          }
        }
      },
      "post": {
        "summary": "error",
        "operationId": "errorUsingPOST",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage",
                  "exampleSetFlag": false
                },
                "exampleSetFlag": false
              }
            }
          },
          "201": {
            "description": "Created"
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "Not Found"
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "summary": "error",
        "operationId": "errorUsingDELETE",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage",
                  "exampleSetFlag": false
                },
                "exampleSetFlag": false
              }
            }
          },
          "204": {
            "description": "No Content"
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden"
          }
        }
      },
      "options": {
        "summary": "error",
        "operationId": "errorUsingOPTIONS",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage",
                  "exampleSetFlag": false
                },
                "exampleSetFlag": false
              }
            }
          },
          "204": {
            "description": "No Content"
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden"
          }
        }
      },
      "head": {
        "summary": "error",
        "operationId": "errorUsingHEAD",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage",
                  "exampleSetFlag": false
                },
                "exampleSetFlag": false
              }
            }
          },
          "204": {
            "description": "No Content"
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden"
          }
        }
      },
      "patch": {
        "summary": "error",
        "operationId": "errorUsingPATCH",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage",
                  "exampleSetFlag": false
                },
                "exampleSetFlag": false
              }
            }
          },
          "204": {
            "description": "No Content"
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden"
          }
        }
      },
      "trace": {
        "summary": "error",
        "operationId": "errorUsingTRACE",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FailureMessage",
                  "exampleSetFlag": false
                },
                "exampleSetFlag": false
              }
            }
          },
          "204": {
            "description": "No Content"
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "Forbidden"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "FailureMessage": {
        "title": "FailureMessage",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "message": {
            "type": "string",
            "exampleSetFlag": false,
            "types": [
              "string"
            ]
          },
          "method": {
            "type": "string",
            "exampleSetFlag": false,
            "types": [
              "string"
            ],
            "enum": [
              "DELETE",
              "GET",
              "HEAD",
              "OPTIONS",
              "PATCH",
              "POST",
              "PUT",
              "TRACE"
            ]
          },
          "request_path": {
            "type": "string",
            "exampleSetFlag": false,
            "types": [
              "string"
            ]
          }
        },
        "exampleSetFlag": false,
        "types": [
          "object"
        ]
      },
      "SuccessMessage": {
        "title": "SuccessMessage",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "message": {
            "type": "string",
            "exampleSetFlag": false,
            "types": [
              "string"
            ]
          }
        },
        "exampleSetFlag": false,
        "types": [
          "object"
        ]
      }
    },
    "extensions": {    }
  }
}
```

Result (it's UI hence the screenshot):

[image]

My Swagger dependencies are:

```xml
<!-- API Gateway -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Gateway: Java 17, Boot 3

```xml
<!-- microservice -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Microservice: Java 17, Boot 2

I obviously want it to group by controllers, as it usually does

Why is Swagger doing it?

Comment: You can try to use tag annotation: https://www.baeldung.com/java-swagger-api-description-deprecated#openapi-3

Comment: @alpert no, no, no, I want Swagger to group them by controllers on its own. I have my own tags that I remove from OpenAPI JSONs, I don't want Swagger to group endpoints by those tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I found

Swagger UI groups endpoints by tags

If no custom tags are added (with `@Tag`), Swagger will automatically create a tag for your controller class that matches that class's name (e.g. `example-controller`). Class-level tags (including default ones Swagger creates) will propagate to every endpoint declared within that controller class

If a controller class or at least one of its methods has its own tag, Swagger will *not* create a default tag for that class. Even if you then manually remove your custom tag from an `OpenApi` object before serving it to Swagger UI, you still won't  have that default tag. What that means is that those tag-less endpoints will be grouped into the "default" group